# Filter on genre in Angular with external API

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm using Angular for this app.
I have a JSON file with in there 5 movies, these movies have an array with Genres.
I want to have links like: /movies/genre/horror
and in it I want to show the movies that contain that genre in it's genres array.

The object in browser: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oF84.png

The JSON file: http://dennistel.nl/movies/

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Can you say what you've tried already, and what difficulties you've had that have prevented you from solving it yourself?

Comment: I've tried to create a route provider: .when('/movies/genres/:genre'. And connect that with a controller that tries to select those genres, but that didn't work. Also for some movies there are multiple genres and I kind of lost it. I'm very new to this, so I might be missing some things that are absolutely needed. I've also tried to create some sort of function and called it in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write the whole thing for you, but going off of what you said you already tried using the route provider, here's an example that should get your where you're trying to go.

```
$routeProvider.when('/movies/genres/:genre', {
  controller: MovieGenresController,
  templateUrl: 'template.html'
});

MovieGenresController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'MoviesService'];
function MovieGenresController($scope, $routeParams, MoviesService) {
  // Making this lowercase will make comparisons easier
  var searchGenre = $routeParams.genre.toLowerCase();

  var movies = MoviesService.getAll();
  var matchingMovies = [];
  angular.forEach(movies, function(movie) {
    if (movie.genres && movie.genres.length) {
      for (var i = 0; i < movie.genres.length; i++) {
        var movieGenre = movie.genres[i].toLowerCase();
        if (movieGenre === searchGenre) {
          matchingMovies.push(movie);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  });

  $scope.movies = matchingMovies;
}
```

This can obviously be optimized, but the general idea is there. You need to take the genre from the $routeParams and loop through the movies to see if they include the genre being searched for, adding them to the array that will eventually be used in your view.

Comment: I'll take a look at this. Thank you for your time and effort!